# Gigabit switch firewall

Tags: networking, firewall, switch

Moving into a new apartment with internet service provided to each apartment.  I can "light-up" all the Ethernet wall jacks with an 8-port switch at the point where the source enters my apartment.  How do I put in a firewall at the source for my apartment to protect all the wall jacks?  Do any switches come with built-in firewalls?
Thanks,
DT13

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much every home consumer router is also a firewall.  Simply plug the  WAN port on the router/firewall combo into the jack provided by your apartment.  This setup will give you your own private network, while still having internet access.  Just search for an "8 port router firewall" in your search engine or online store of your choice.

Comment: There's a really wide variety of firewallish capabilities that routers may or may not support. Almost all SOHO routers do network address address translation ("NAT") for IP version 4, which sort of functions as a basic firewall, but some can do far more. Also, the world is (sloooooowly) migrating to IP version 6, which doesn't do NAT; some routers provide some sort of IPv6 firewalling, some don't, and some don't support it at all (which doesn't matter much now, especially if the building's Internet connection doesn't support IPv6 yet, but will in the future).